# Python data structure similar to dictionary where key is two values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking for a data structure in Python that is similar to a dictionary. The difference is that there is two keys. I want to be able to access the value in constant time.
Like:

```
dict.get(dog, smurf)
{(dog, smurf): 40}
```

Is this possible?

If this doesn't exist, I would just do a dictionary in a dictionary. But, the above would be more convenient.

```
{dog: {(smurf: 40)}}
```

Comment: a couple of comments:  don't call a dict `dict`.  and dict.get(dog, smurf) would be interpreted by someone who reads python as meaning `dict[dog] if dog in dict else smurf`, which is not what you are meaning in this case!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What's stopping you?

```
d = {(dog, smurf): 40}
print d[(dog, smurf)] # 40
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even know that. I guess I should have probably tried it first.

Answer (score 4):

I don't quite understand your example. Do you mean something like this?

```
>>> dog = 'dog'
>>> smurf = 'smurf'
>>> d = {(dog, smurf): 40}
>>> d[(dog, smurf)]
40
```

Tuples are immutable, and if the objects they contain are also immutable, then they can be used as dictionary keys too.

But if you assign a mutable object to `dog`, it won't work:

```
>>> dog = ['d', 'o', 'g']
>>> d[(dog, smurf)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I didn't know that was possible, though.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, you can use a normal dict indexing with a tuple.  If the keys are both hashable, then the (immutable) tuple will be hashable and can be used as a dict key.

```
>>> d = {('dog', 'smurf'): 123}
>>> d[('dog', 'smurf')]
123
>>> d.get(('dog', 'smurf'))
123
```

If you *really* want to use `d.get` without the duplicated parentheses, then inherit from `dict` and override the `get` method and/or `__getitem__`, to be using tuple packing/unpacking.  But don't do that if you don't need to for a good reason.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the parens:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['jim', 'joe'] = 7
>>> d['jim', 'joe']
7
>>> d
{('jim', 'joe'): 7}
```

Tuples aren't signified by parens. They're signified by the comma. The parens are only needed sometimes for disambiguation.